# Algorithm to determine all possibilities for names given an array [in PHP]?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

Mismatch between code here & code in project caused problem.

Comment: Your script never ends because there are only 10*10 different ways to combine the words.

Comment: There's ninety combinations assuming you don't use the same word twice and `w1w2` is different from `w2w1`. I don't know where you got 2^10 from

Comment: It's 10*10 if you allow combining a word with itself. It's 10*9 if you want combinations of distinct words. It's 10*9/2 if the order of the two words doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($words as $first) {
    foreach ($words as $second) {
        $taken[] = $first.$second;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only 324, shouldn't there be more?

Comment: This doesn't give every possibility.

Comment: This did the trick, I had a mismatch between my post & actual script that caused the confusion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all possible combinations without having duplicates (ex:w1w1), use this:

```
$allCombinations = null;
$words = array('w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5', 'w6', 'w7', 'w8', 'w9', 'w10');

foreach ($words as $word1)
{
    foreach ($words as $word2)
    {
        if ($word1 != $word2)
        {
            $allCombinations[] = $word1.$word2;
        }
    }
}

echo count ($allCombinations); // The count is 90, and that's what it should be.
print_r($allCombinations);
```

Comment: Still doesn't give all possibilities (only 305).

Comment: There should only be 100 possibilities (10^2), minus the duplicates which I have removed. Your equation is wrong and so is your 305, I don't know where you're getting that.

Comment: See comment above.  Thanks.